# Constraint layout in practice look different than in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to place my views into ConstraintLayout, but every views like button/textview look different in real device than in AndroidStudio.

Check how its look:

[in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTX5c.png)
[in real Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTPi9.png)

It's looks horrible ! How I can fix that ? What I should do ?
I thought it was the easiest way to arrange views.

and my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.LoginActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="228dp"
        android:text="Login"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.275"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.599" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="User"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.63" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDefault"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="184dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="364dp"
        android:text="default user"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I have no issues, so that is not it

Comment: It looks like what Android Studio is showing you is just wrong. Take your two buttons for example, they have completely different vertical bias so I wouldn't expect them to be aligned. I'd suggest constraining the buttons and other objects to each other rather than positioning everything relative to the screen edges.

Comment: I thought I'd add that technically, it looks the same in AS and on a real device _if_ you're using the same device version. That layout works on 1 particular screen size only. You can select a different device emulator in AS preview or switch to a landscape mode. In both cases, the layout would fall apart. Seems like the layout editor simply hardcoded all values. That's why it's always better to code it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of `ConstraintLayout` is to use constraints to position views relative to each other. In your case you try to constrain each view in relation to the parent and then use bias to position the view which is the reason everything seems out of order.

Here is the simple example XML that will give you a basic idea how to position these views using constraints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.LoginActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="User"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/etLogin"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/etLogin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etLogin" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btnDefault"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/etLogin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDefault"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="default user"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/etLogin"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btnLogin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etPassword" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The result:

[image]

If you want to add some spacing between the views you can experiment with adding some margins between them.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked this for syntax, but something like this might work better (tying things to each other, rather than to the screen edges).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.LoginActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="228dp"
        android:text="Login"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/etPassword"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnDefault"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etPassword"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="User"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/etLogin"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etLogin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etLogin" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDefault"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="184dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="364dp"
        android:text="default user"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnLogin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etPassword" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```